# Admob: Force Android device to re-use same advertising ID after factory reset

Tags: android, admob, root

**Background:**

I have developed an app which has features for root users. Therefore, I have to test it on a rooted device, and sometimes this device must be restored to factory settings (i.e. if something got wrong, or a new firmware / ROM combination must be tested). When that has been done, it has a new device ID and I start to get real ads if I open the current production version of the app on this device. As I only have 1 device to work with, I cannot install the production version (which i sometimes check to see if everything is all right) on another device.

**Current implementation:**

The test device IDs are coded into the AdRequest in the app, just like Google recommends in their documentation. One thing I can think of is storing them on my server and sending these with one of the network requests that are made by the app, but I don't really like that (putting test code in production API).

**My question:**

Basically: I want to keep getting test ads on my test phone after having performed a factory restore, without having to make changes to my code and having to submit a new app version to Google Play. Is there some possibility to re-set the old device ID (the one the device had before factory resetting) as the current one, so the device continues to receive test ads? Can anybody tell me how they deal with this situation? If it were not possible, would it be better to create an emulator (AVD) which only runs production builds of the app in non-rooted mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can register (in app) simple broadcast receiver, that upon sending correct request will add to white list current deviceId, and store it somewhere (shared prefs for example).

This way you can have single app in production and dynamically add to white list device id via adb command line ./adb shell am broadcast